# MySQL запись вставляется в начало

Tags: php, mysql

Запись добавляется в начало таблицы а не в конец, в чём может быть проблема?

[image]

16 это последняя запись которая находится снизу, то что было после неё было удалено.

Имеется такой запрос

```
$sett['msg_limit'] = 15;
    if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `msg` WHERE (`who` = '".$_GET['msg']."' && `whom` = '$id') || (`who` = '$id' && `whom` = '".$_GET['msg']."')")) > $sett['msg_limit']) {
    $msg_limit = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `msg` WHERE (`who` = '".$_GET['msg']."' && `whom` = '$id') || (`who` = '$id' && `whom` = '".$_GET['msg']."')"))-$sett['msg_limit'];
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM `msg` WHERE (`who` = '".$_GET['msg']."' && `whom` = '$id') || (`who` = '$id' && `whom` = '".$_GET['msg']."') LIMIT ".$msg_limit);
    }
```

это таблица которая содержит сообщения. верхний код чистит всё сообщения кроме последних $sett['msg_limit'] сообщений.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сортируйте вывод по id, или по дате в зависимости от ситуации, и поддерживаю [[@Равнодушный](/users/8603/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)](/users/8603/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) код ужасен! У вас там SQL-иньекция. Считайте что это парадный вход для всяких ламо-хакеров.
Используйте [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.pdo-mysql.php) и выкиньте тот мануал или что там, по которому вы это писали. Так код не пишут уже давно.

Comment: Вы только SQL-инъекцию увидели? Я Вас огорчу, но еще не факт, что она там есть. А вот чтобы решить задачу, в которой явно напрашивается один запрос, не очевидными 3мя запросами - надо родиться в Индии...

Comment: @Равнодушный, вы вот сейчас совсем свой ник не оправдываете...

Comment: @LTKH, мне не важно Ваше мнение о моём нике.

Comment: @Равнодушный, вот теперь в самый раз.

Comment: @Равнодушный, что увидел, то сказал. Даже сейчас после вашего коммента только с третьего раза разглядел в этой каше код. Человек очевидно новичок, исправится.

@Равнодушный, добрее надо с людям =)

Answer (score 7):

У таблицы нет понятий "начало" и "конец". Код - несусветная ересь. Просто оторвите руки, тому, кто это писал и найдите другого программиста.

Comment: @Равнодушный, как бы не получилось так, что автор вопроса и "кодер", это написавший - одно и то же лицо :)

Comment: Сомневаюсь, ибо автор вопроса явно не понимает, что написано в этом коде.